# How to include conditional installs in python packages -- namely for backports?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging, python-importlib

My question is about conditional installs in general, but the usage I have in mind is for python backports specifically. Let's do this with a concrete example.

It often happens that I want to use `from importlib.resources import files`, but that only exists in 3.9+.

In my code, I end up doing:

```py
try:
    from importlib.resources import files  # ... and any other things you want to get
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
    from importlib_resources import files  # pip install importlib_resources
```

But I feel shame when copy/pasting this code everywhere. Additionally, it still doesn't solve my problem "completely".
The question is: Do I include `importlib_resources`, a third-party backport of `importlib.resources`, in my `setup.cfg` `install_requires`? If I don't, my code will fail on python < 3.9. If I do include it, I'm overkilling my dependencies.

Ideally, I'd like a solution where I can just do

```py
from importlib_resources import files
```

in my code, and trust that the `setup.cfg` took care of doing two things:

- telling the install to only do a `pip install importlib-resources` if python version < 3.9
- telling it that `importlib_resources` is an alias for `importlib.resources` if in 3.9+, and of `importlib_resources` (the pip install backport) if not.

Trying to solve the first problem only, I did this.

```
install_requires =
    dol
    importlib_resources; python_version < '3.9'
```

But it doesn't condition the install at all (it's installed on both 3.8 and 3.10!).

Not sure how to even start with the second "aliasing" desire.

Comment: This is the correct way of specifying dependencies, see [this](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/45ed55a9f19032718337c0fdd0176b34667d392b/pyproject.toml#L38) for a similar example.  -- For the import, a good way is: `try: import importlib.resources as importlib_resources; except ImportError: import importlib_resources`, but you can also do like [this](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/45ed55a9f19032718337c0fdd0176b34667d392b/src/build/util.py#L15-L18). I do not think there is another way around it, there has to be 2 import statements, no "shame" in this.

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc. The [if_version-else](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/45ed55a9f19032718337c0fdd0176b34667d392b/src/build/util.py#L15-L18) way you mention has its merits, but I prefer the try-except way (less variable surface, so less error prone). Not sure it's worth having a function to encompass this logic, but I tried it out anyway. You can find it [here](https://github.com/i2mint/wads/discussions/10?converting=1#discussioncomment-5252314), or [here (with docs)](https://github.com/i2mint/wads/blob/c788a47017de60f19861f12f0e47455462f52014/wads/util.py#L373)

Comment: The "*if else*" and "*try except*" are very common idioms, and yes they are very commonly used in this particular case (importing something that may or may not be importable/installed), for example for optional features/plugins. You can of course replace it with a custom written function call, but to me it means trying quite hard to hide something that everyone knows exists and is well understood.

Comment: If really the "conditional import" bothers you, then just rely on the external backport  `importlib_resources` exclusively and ignore the standard lib `importlib.resources` one, for as long as you need to support Python versions that do not have `importlib.resources.files()`. When the time comes where all Python versions you want to support all have `importlib.resources.files` in the standard library then and only then switch to it. This is a perfectly viable solution. The backport is always more up-to-date and has the latest performance improvements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If really the "conditional import" bothers you, then just rely on the external backport  `importlib_resources` exclusively and ignore the standard lib `importlib.resources` one, for as long as you need to support Python versions that do not have `importlib.resources.files()`. When the time comes where all Python versions you want to support all have `importlib.resources.files()` in their standard library, then and only then switch to it. This is a perfectly viable solution. The backport is always more up-to-date and has the latest performance improvements anyway.

---

For Python before version 3.9 (before the introduction of `importlib.resources.files()`), `importlib.resources` contained other methods to access package data (that are now deprecated in favor of `files()`). So it would be possible to write code that covers quite a wide range of Python interpreter versions without relying on the `importlib_resources` backport.

See [*`importlib.resoures` "Deprecated functions"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#deprecated-functions).

---

Yes, `importlib_resources; python_version < '3.9'` is the correct way to specify such a conditional dependency.

---

If you want to import either `importlib.resources` or `importlib_resources` in the same code base, then there are two very common and well understood techniques:

```py
try:
    from importlib.resources import files
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
    from importlib_resources import files
```

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
    from importlib.resources import files
else:
    from importlib_resources import files
```

Comment: Actually, the code snippets you proposed wouldn't work. You'd always get the builtin version, and get an `AttributeError` error only once you try to access `files`. Further, call me perfectionist, but though `importlib-resources` is really light, in packages with no, or few dependencies, **any** seems like a scratch on un otherwise perfect surface.

Comment: "*the code snippets you proposed wouldn't work*", ah... you are probably right, I think I understand what is incorrect, I will try to fix.

Comment: "*call me perfectionist, but though importlib-resources is really light, in packages with no, or few dependencies, any seems like a scratch on un otherwise perfect surface*". I am trying to lay down the facts relevant to your question to the best of my knowledge. The decision you make is entirely in your hands. -- Also note that for Python before 3.9 (before `importlib.resources.files()`) there were other possibilites (that are now deprecated in favor of `files()`) that you could use to be completely dependency-free. It's in the docs.